# token_counter always return 0 value when using DocumentSummaryIndex with get_response_synthesizer

Tags: prompt, llama-index

Llama Index token_count is not working on my code.

```
    llm = MockLLM(max_tokens=256)
    embed_model = MockEmbedding(embed_dim=1536)
    

    token_counter = TokenCountingHandler(
        tokenizer=tiktoken.encoding_for_model("gpt-3.5-turbo").encode
    )

    callback_manager = CallbackManager([token_counter])

    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
        llm=llm, 
        embed_model=embed_model, 
        callback_manager=callback_manager
    )

    response_synthesizer = get_response_synthesizer(
        summary_template = _chat_summarize_prompt(),  # TreeSummarize prompt
        text_qa_template = _chat_qa_prompt(),         # qa prompt
        response_mode    = "tree_summarize",
        use_async        = True,
    )

    doc_summary_index = DocumentSummaryIndex.from_documents(
        documents, # You need documents before execute this function
        response_synthesizer = response_synthesizer,
        service_context      = service_context,
        summary_query        = _summary_prompt(), # summary prompt
    )
    
    print(
    "Embedding Tokens: ",
    token_counter.total_embedding_token_count,
    "\n",
    "LLM Prompt Tokens: ",
    token_counter.prompt_llm_token_count,
    "\n",
    "LLM Completion Tokens: ",
    token_counter.completion_llm_token_count,
    "\n",
    "Total LLM Token Count: ",
    token_counter.total_llm_token_count,
    "\n",
    )
    
    
    # reset counts
    token_counter.reset_counts()
```

Llamaindex's token_counter is not supported on DocmentSummaryIndex?
So, maybe need original token_counter?
Llamaindex's token_counter is not supported on DocmentSummaryIndex?
So, maybe need original token_counter?
Llamaindex's token_counter is not supported on DocmentSummaryIndex?
So, maybe need original token_counter?
Llamaindex's token_counter is not supported on DocmentSummaryIndex?
So, maybe need original token_counter?

Comment: Have you tried setting the service context using `set_global_service_context` instead of passing to the `from_documents(...)` method? But regardless of this, I believe that you must actively query against the created index with some specific question/prompt to utilize the counting of tokens. Otherwise, it will not register anything and that could explain why you are consistently getting 0 counts. Feel free to return with updates on how it went.